# NetworkX Test Failure

Tags: python, networkx, pyzo

I installed NetworkX via conda on pyzo4.4.1. The python version I use is 3.6.1

```
conda install networkx
conda update networkx
```

As it is suggested in the installation guide of NetworkX, I also installed nose for testing and ran the full test with the following command:

```
import networkx as nx
nx.test()
```

To my surprise, it yielded 57 failed tests. Here is a link to the [complete log](https://justpaste.it/19poe). Here's a short summary:

```
Failure:
test_kcomponents.test_example_1_detail_3_and_4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Approximate current-flow betweenness centrality: K4
 # in total there are 9 other failed tests concerning betweenness centrality
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_hits.TestHITS.test_hits
 # 4 of these
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_pagerank.TestPageRank.test_dangling_pagerank
 # 12 of these
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_branchings.test_greedy_max1
  # 4 of these
...
```

I tried removing the networkx and decorator and reinstalling it via conda. I then removed it yet again and installed via pip, still it does not work.
I need some of the functions that are failing the tests (for example betweenness). Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should be reported to NetworkX's bugtracker: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues If possible, could you check the results of tests with a standard Python environment on the same computer?

Comment: I just ran `python -c "import networkx as nx; nx.test()"` but it results in the same failures. I forgot to mention that I'm running this on Ubuntu 16.04. I'll Try installing networkx on my windows 10 partition (again using pyzo) right now.

Comment: Just installed pyzo on my windows partition and added networkx and related modules, still I get exactly 57 failures. Interestingly there are 5 Skips on the windows partition and it took about 90 seconds. On Ubuntu It took a little under 60 seconds and it only skipped 4 tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current release of `networkx` does not support Python 3.6.  We will release `networkx` 2.0 soon and this will no longer be an issue.  The 2.0 release changes quite a few things, which is why it has taken longer to finalize than previous releases.  Thanks for your patience.

You can follow 2.0 development here:

https://github.com/networkx/networkx/milestone/3

and read a draft of the release notes here:

http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/news.html

You can install the current master branch using:

```
$ pip install git+http://github.com/networkx/networkx
```

The master branch should be in good shape and we would love additional feedback on it as we finalize the 2.0 release.